# Standard Error of MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-error

I have a model and a vector of parameters that I estimate using ML. Since I'm doing a MonteCarlo I can simulate as many times as I want, i.e. data is not real data. I was just wondering how I can compute the Standard Errors of my estimator and what their significance is.

Comment: So are you estimating the parameters with ML or MC?

Comment: Maximum Likelihood

Comment: Then MLE theory indicates that $\sqrt{n} \left( \hat{\theta} - \theta \right) \rightarrow_d \mathcal{N} \left( 0, \mathcal{I} ^{-1} \left( \theta \right) \right)$. So you should just use the information to estimate your standard errors.

Comment: How are you obtaining the MLE? If your optimization routine returns the Hessian (e.g., `optim` in `R` usually produces this), your standard errors are the square root of the diagonal of the inverse of the negative of the Hessian. In R: `sqrt(diag(solve(-Hessian)))`. Depending on the software you use -- whether the routine is maximizing the likelihood or minimizing the negative of the likelihood -- you may or may not need the negative in front of the Hessian. Most of the routines in `R` minimize, thus the need for the negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 3 "[Bootstrap Standard Error](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~xshi/econ715/Lecture_10_bootstrap.pdf)" of this lecture for theory. This should give you enough information to search for an example code for your software of choice. Some excerpts follow:

```
I start with the third purpose of bootstrap: to obtain standard error for an estimator... 
Bootstrap standard errors are used as an alternative of the usual asymptotic standard error...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found https://files.nyu.edu/mrg217/public/mle_introduction1.pdf shortly after I asked the question and it essentially says the same thing as the notes that you shared say.